# How to simplify "median of medians" formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, median

Given a nested median formula:

$
\operatorname{med}\big(
\operatorname{med}(a_{1,1},\ldots,a_{1,n}),
\operatorname{med}(a_{2,1},\ldots,a_{2,n}),
\ldots,
\operatorname{med}(a_{k,1},\ldots,a_{k,n})
\big)
$

Is there a rule for simplifying this formula (making it not nested)?

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm to compute this value that doesn't involve computing all of the intermediate medians? The expression seems pretty concise to me.